# Java: how to save SET<Integer> as value in HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, set

I want to have the following data structure to store a word with its multiple IDs (int), but I don't know how to put the key-value pair into the following variable "myWord"

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> myWord = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
```

myWord.put("word1", how to add the ID to the Set here?)

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> myWord = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();
myWord.put("word1", mySet);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>(); // create a set of IDs
mySet.add(1); // add Id to set
mySet.add(2); // add Id to set
myWord.put("word1", mySet); // finally put set in your map
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<>();
set.add(id);// Similarly all ids here
myWord.put("word1", set)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();
mySet.add(3);
Map<String, Set<Integer>> myWord = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();

myWord.put("word1", mySet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using a [HashMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html), which more powerfully represents the data structure you are trying to build.

```
Multimap<String, Integer> myWord = HashMultimap.create();
myWord.put("word1", 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>(); // create a set of ids for each word
mySet.add(1); // add Id to the set
mySet.add(2); // add Id to the set
myWord.put("word1", mySet); // for every word put the corresponding set in the map
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> adjacent = new HashMap<Integer,Set<Integer>>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int nodeA = s.nextInt();
        int nodeB = s.nextInt();
        if (!adjacent.containsKey(nodeA)) { **checking if the nodes contains A** 
            adjacent.put(nodeA, new HashSet<Integer>()); **If node A is not present it is being added**
        } 
        adjacent.get(nodeA).add(nodeB); **At the end node B is added to node A's list**
    }
```